# condition / directive in Angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm just starting out with angular. I currently have an json array of products being displayed within an ng-repeat and am looking to add a class to every third product.

Is there a way to write a condition within the repeater that will add a class to the html element when the index%3 is 2

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure!

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items' ng-class='{third: $index%3==2}'>{{item}}</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/24Ne1Cyh71INYIKxBCcc

Comment: Would it be possible to only add this class if $index%3 was equal to 2 rather than every item?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the `ng-class` directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{ 'third-elm': $index%3 == 2 }">{{item.value}}</div>
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/dKjz5/